# How to use random module to choose between three strings?

Tags: python, tkinter

So this program prints 30 concentric circles in the middle of my canvas, I am trying to make each circle a random color using a function that I have to call, I don't really know why this doesn't work. Can you tell me: A. Why doesn't this work the way it is now? B. How can I fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
root = Tk()

w, h = 800, 600
c = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg="gold")
c.pack()
```

so this is the part that I need help with:

```
def colors(r = "Red", p = "Purple", b = "Blue"):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        choice([r, p, b])


colors("Red","Purple","Blue")
```

And also need help with calling the function

```
cx, cy = w//2, h//2
z = 5
for _ in range(30):
    c.create_oval(cx-z, cy-z, cx+z, cy+z, width=2, outline = colors(r, p, b))                                                           
    z += 5
```

Thanks a lot!

full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
root = Tk()

w, h = 800, 600
c = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg="gold")
c.pack()


def random_colors(r = "Red", p = "Purple", b = "Blue"):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        choice([r, p, b])


random_colors("Red","Purple","Blue")
    
cx, cy = w//2, h//2
z = 5
for _ in range(30):
    c.create_oval(cx-z, cy-z, cx+z, cy+z, width=2, outline = choice([r,p,b])
z+= 5
```

root.mainloop()

Comment: Just change `random.randint(r, p, b)` to random.choice((r, p, b))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make this better by passing your own colors as arguments

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

root = Tk()

w, h = 800, 600
c = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg="gold")
c.pack()

def colors(*args):
    default = ['red','purple','blue'] # main set of colors
    args = [_ for _ in args] # custom passed color
    color_lst = args + default # list of all colors passed and default
    color = choice(color_lst) #choosing a random color from the list
    return color #returning the color
    
cx, cy = w//2, h//2
z = 5
for _ in range(30):
    c.create_oval(cx-z, cy-z, cx+z, cy+z, width=2, outline = colors('orange','white'))  #calling the function with extra 2 colors                                                          
    z += 5

root.mainloop()
```

I've explained it with comments to make you understand while reading it. Also its better to say `from random import choice` or `import random` because or else it might pollute your namespace.

Comment: thx! I used ur comment up top^ It works perfectly now!

Comment: ok thanks. it might look like I'm trying to get the "vote thirty times in a day" badge because I'm still considered a noob... but no worries wont do it again

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `random.choice`:

```
In [28]: from random import *
    ...:
    ...: def random_colors(r, p, b):
    ...:     r = "Red"
    ...:     p = "Purple"
    ...:     b = "Blue"
    ...:     for i in range(0, 3):
    ...:         print(choice([r, p, b]))
    ...:
    ...: random_colors("Red","Purple","Blue")
Purple
Red
Red
```

And are you looking for default values?

```
from random import *

def random_colors(r = "Red", p = "Purple", b = "Blue"):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        print(choice([r, p, b]))

random_colors("Red","Purple","Blue")
```

Comment: `range(0, 3)` equal to `range(3)` and it's good to use `_` as variable name if you don't use it. Also you can use *tuple* `(r, p, b)` instead of *list*.

Comment: so I didn't ask my question well enough, I edited It, can you take a look now?

Comment: What is the purpose of `range(0,3)`, it will just print 3 random colors.